# React renders a blank page instead of a JSON feed

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I have a React app running on the Express backend; the website functions well.

On a dedicated URL - **herokuapp.com/apii** - I want to show a JSON data feed (eg. [like this](https://newsapi.org/)) that would serve for a mobile app to fetch data from

This is my **app.js** (server):

```
const express = require('express'),
      path = require('path'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      passport = require('passport');

const app = express();
const apii = require('./backend/routes/apii');
...
// Serve static files from the React app -- added because of Heroku, the local app doesn't need this
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/build')));

app.use(passport.initialize());
require('./backend/passport')(passport);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/apii', apii);
app.get('*', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './react-ui/build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on PORT ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Then, **./backend/routes/apii**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var testObject = {
        "AppName": "MongoPop",
        "Version": 1.0
    }
    res.json(testObject);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here's the React's routing:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <Provider store = { store }>
            <Router>
              <div>
                <Navbar />
                <Router exact path="/" component={ Home } />
                <div className="container">
                    <Route exact path="/home" component={ Home } />
                    <Route exact path="/about" component={ About } />
                </div>
              </div>
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Routes like **herokuapp.com/home** or **herokuapp.com/about** work well, however, when I try to put to the browser **herokuapp.com/apii**, I get a blank page, the JSON object *testObject* is not displayed (only a blank white page, as mentioned earlier).

However, if I put the URL **herokuapp.com/apii** to [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), I do see there *testObject*:
[image]

Why is the JSON structure not rendered in the browser?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "when I try to put to the browser herokuapp.com/apii". Do you mean that you are doing a `PUT` request? Have you tried a `GET` request? It might also be that your API doesn't have CORS enabled. Check the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: I am executing `GET` requests everywhere.

Comment: However, if I try to type `http://localhost:5000/apii`, I get the expected JSON

Comment: Yes, that was what I was alluding to in last part of my comment. Try looking in the networks tab of your Developer Tools. `herokuapp.com/apii` might be giving you CORS issues.

Comment: There's no route for `apii` in your React Router config. Or a route for a 404 page this way you can see why your code isn't working.